# An SQL Server database with user name and password only

Tags: sql-server, authentication

I want to create a database in SQL Server 2012 which is accessible only through my own developed application. This database should not be accessible to 'Windows Authentication' or any other user. I am trying this by adding a login to SQL Server and then mapping this login to my database but this is not working. Is there anyone who help me out in this problem?

Comment: This is not really a good practice. DBAs, backup applications all need some level of access to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You go to the Database with MSMS, create a user-id and PSW with the required permission and set the user-id and psw in the connectionstring